# Rmarkdown files isn't knitting, it doesn't allow to execute a for cycle

Tags: r

Here is a code, that runs fine within an R script:

````
```{r }
n <- c(10,20,10,20,50)
m <- c(10,10,20,20,50)
n <- 50
m <- 50
s1 <- c(1,1)
s2 <- c(1,25) #standartnovisrzes sadalījumiem
N<- 10000 #atkārtojumu skaits
emp <- c()
for (k in 1:2){
for (j in 1:5){
  resamples1 <- lapply(1:N, function(i) rnorm(n[j], 0, s1[k]))
  resamples2 <- lapply(1:N, function(i) rnorm(m[j], 0, s2[k]))
  t.rez_var_equal <- mapply(resamples1, resamples2,                     
                            FUN=function(x,y) t.test(x,y, var.equal=T))
  t_rez <- mapply(resamples1, resamples2,                     
                  FUN=function(x,y) t.test(x,y))
  t_wilcox <- mapply(resamples1, resamples2,                     
                     FUN=function(x,y) wilcox.test(x,y))
  t.pval.var.equal <- unlist(t.rez_var_equal[3,])
  t.pval <- unlist(t_rez[3,])
  t.pval.wilcox <- unlist(t_wilcox[3,])
  emp_05_tvequal <- length(t.pval.var.equal[t.pval.var.equal<=0.05])/N
  emp_05_t <- length(t.pval[t.pval<=0.05])/N
  emp_05_twilcox <- length(t.pval.wilcox[t.pval.wilcox<=0.05])/N
  emp <- append(emp, c(emp_05_tvequal, emp_05_t, emp_05_twilcox))
  emp
}}
```
````

But when trying to knitr the document, it throws an error about the 9th line:

```
resamples1 <- lapply(1:N, function(i) rnorm(n[j], 0, s1[k]))
```

The error message: `Error in rnorm(n[j], 0, s1[k])): invalid argument Calls: <Anonymous>... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> lapply -> FUN -> rnorm Execution halted.`
Maybe R doesn't allow cycles in Rmarkdown files?

Comment: Hard-coding indexing is a bad idea. By that I mean `for (j in 1:5)`, when you assume that `n[j]` will work. It is far more defensive (and general and adaptable and flexible) to use something like `for (j in seq_along(n))` or `for (j in seq_len(length(n)))`; don't use `for (j in 1:length(n))`, as this fails when `n` is (inadvertently?) length 0, since `1:0` is actually length 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accidentally overwriting variables `n` and `m` right after they are declared. So that both of them have length of 1. And when you try to access any other position in `n[i]` it returns `NA` which throws this error inside `rnorm` function.

This isn't related to Rmarkdown but rather to the fact that when kniting a file it runs all lines in the script and when you run it "manually" you can cherry-pick only the lines you want to run, which you probably did and that's why it worked in script.